# Retrieve email contents with correct encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, gmail-api

I am trying to retrieve the body of some emails from my Gmail account following the example specified at the following [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

However, from the code below, I do not understand why is the raw message encoded into ASCII:

```
msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
```

Could someone please explain why is this conversion happening, from the documentation I read, the raw message is already b64url encoded, so I do not understand the need for the extra step?

Also, my second question is how do I get the original message encoding to allow me to write the email to a file with the correct encoding; looking at the documentation, I do not see anything relevant to point to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlsafe_b64decode` can only take bytes (a string), not unicode.
Since the raw message only contains ASCII data it is safe to encode your unicode code points as ASCII.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure whether it is guaranteed that the raw message is always going to have only ASCII characters, I haven't been able to find this in the documentation; I guess it is a well-known convention?

Comment: @Spektor Yeah, [**base64 data**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is just a format for representing binary data in an ASCII format.